envio whatsapp + registros bd + php + js
Estoy enviando un mensaje a whatsapp con unos registros de la bd, utilizando un input mostrando esos datos en php con un echo y utilizo una funcion en js funciona perfectamente lo redirecciona bien, pero al estar en el mensaje solo me muestra un dato de multiples registros que existen, quiero que en el mensaje de muestre todos los registros y si se puede ordenados con salto de linea

este es mi codigo
function setNombre() {
var miUrl = " https://wa.me/12312312?text=" + document.getElementById("txtNombre").value;
window.open(miUrl);
                }

<input id="txtNombre" 
value="
<?php echo $arreglo[$i]['Nombre']; ?> 
<?php echo $arreglo[$i]['Cantidad']; ?>
<?php echo $arreglo[$i]['Precio']; ?>
      ">
         <?php } ?>
<button id="btnWAPP" type="button" onclick="setNombre()">Mi url</button>


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

disculpen lo que sucede es que no queria comentar tantas lineas explicandolo pense que se entendia pero vi queno.. ya pude solucionar el problema que tenia. lo unico que tenia que agregar un substr y la variable que tenia en mi foreach

gracias por compartir @user355913.
Puedes compartir tu solución en una respuesta, de este modo otros podrian venficiare de esa respuesta. Respondes a tu preunta con la solución, y luego la aceptas

Puedes usar %0a para separar por líneas en tu url. Aunque en la vista previa no se vea el salto de línea, cuando se envíe el mensaje se agrega.
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=11111111&text=123%0A456%0A789




utilizando textos me serviria pero en mi caso como lo agrego utilizando mi variable?                                                                                                    var miUrl = " https://wa.me/12312312?text=" + document.getElementById("txtNombre").value;
